# How to handle Undefined control sequence when exporting jupyter notebook to pdf?

Tags: latex, ipython, jupyter, pandoc, nbconvert

I have a few of Jupyter 4.1.0 notebooks which I am exporting to .pdf files using the `nbconvert` utility:

`jupyter nbconvert --to pdf "Data analysis.ipynb" --template report`

I have `MikTex 2.9` installed along with almost latest `pandoc`.
Most of the notebooks are exported nicely, however, some produce Latex related errors, for instance:

```
! Undefined control sequence.

<argument> ...f.State\_name\ ==\ \textquotesingle 

                                                  {}California\textquotesing...

l.958 ...esingle{}California\textquotesingle{}{]}}
```

I could figure out that Latex didn't like having

> This time we will not run `df[df.State_name == 'California']`

in the cell of markdown type.

Another cell had `u''` in the markdown and another error was thrown:

```
! Undefined control sequence.

<argument> u\textquotesingle 

                             {}\textquotesingle {}

l.535 ...tt{u\textquotesingle{}\textquotesingle{}}

                                                   in front of the keys is
```

I can easily fix those issues by moving the code from markdown to the code cell.

I can also make this particular cell of `Raw NBConvert` type, but then I lack nice layout in the notebook and cannot get code shown highlighted along the regular text.

**I am wondering if there is any kind of cheat sheet to look up to keep in mind what kind of things in Jupyter notebook nbconvert/Latex won't like so I don't have to clean it up later on.**